Add 30 working days excluding weekends and bank holidays
I have a date picker control.  When the use selects a date, I want a textbox to give 30 working days later, excluding weekends and bank holidays.  This is what I have at the moment.
Switch (CountIf(BankHolidayDates, BankHolidayDate >= 

StartDate.SelectedDate, BankHolidayDate <= DateAdd(StartDate.SelectedDate,
Value(gvDaysToDeadline)  +
RoundDown(gvDaysToDeadline / 5, 0)*2+
Switch(Weekday(StartDate.SelectedDate),5,If(Mod( gvDaysToDeadline , 5)>0,2,0),
                                           4,If(Mod( gvDaysToDeadline , 5)>1,2,0),
                                           3,If(Mod( gvDaysToDeadline , 5)>2,2,0),
                                           2,If(Mod( gvDaysToDeadline , 5)>3,2,0),
                                           1,If(Mod( gvDaysToDeadline , 5)>4,2,0))
)),0,DateAdd(StartDate.SelectedDate,
Value(gvDaysToDeadline)  +
RoundDown(gvDaysToDeadline / 5, 0)*2+
Switch(Weekday(StartDate.SelectedDate),5,If(Mod( gvDaysToDeadline , 5)>0,2,0),
                                           4,If(Mod( gvDaysToDeadline , 5)>1,2,0),
                                           3,If(Mod( gvDaysToDeadline , 5)>2,2,0),
                                           2,If(Mod( gvDaysToDeadline , 5)>3,2,0),
                                           1,If(Mod( gvDaysToDeadline , 5)>4,2,0))
),1,DateAdd(StartDate.SelectedDate,
Value(gvDaysToDeadline+1)  +
RoundDown((gvDaysToDeadline+1) / 5, 0)*2+
Switch(Weekday(StartDate.SelectedDate),5,If(Mod( gvDaysToDeadline+1 , 5)>0,2,0),
                                           4,If(Mod( gvDaysToDeadline+1 , 5)>1,2,0),
                                           3,If(Mod( gvDaysToDeadline+1 , 5)>2,2,0),
                                           2,If(Mod( gvDaysToDeadline+1 , 5)>3,2,0),
                                           1,If(Mod( gvDaysToDeadline+1 , 5)>4,2,0))
),2,DateAdd(StartDate.SelectedDate,
Value(gvDaysToDeadline+2)  +
RoundDown((gvDaysToDeadline+2) / 5, 0)*2+
Switch(Weekday(StartDate.SelectedDate),5,If(Mod( gvDaysToDeadline+2 , 5)>0,2,0),
                                           4,If(Mod( gvDaysToDeadline+2 , 5)>1,2,0),
                                           3,If(Mod( gvDaysToDeadline+2 , 5)>2,2,0),
                                           2,If(Mod( gvDaysToDeadline+2 , 5)>3,2,0),
                                          1,If(Mod( gvDaysToDeadline+2 , 5)>4,2,0))
))


Which country's banks?

UK.  I have the list of dates in a Sharepoint list rather than hardcoding.  It will be up to the user to maintain that list.

I ingest the Bank holidays list into a powerapps collection which is OK.  Then I'm trying to exclude weekends which is where I'm struggling.

You can use something similar to the expression below:
With(
    { next9Weeks: ForAll(
        Sequence(63), // Next 9 weeks
        DateAdd(DatePickerCanvas1.SelectedDate,Value)) },
    With(
        {
            nextBusinessDays: Filter(
                next9Weeks,
                Weekday(Value, StartOfWeek.Monday) <= 5  // Monday-Friday
                    And Not (Value in bankHolidays)) },  // Exclude bank holidays
        Index(nextBusinessDays, 30).Value))

Where bankHolidays is a single-column collection / table with the dates for the holidays.
If there is the possibility of more than 15 bank holidays in any 9-week period you will need to increase the number of days to look ahead.

Does the column heading in the bank holidays list need to be "value"?  At the moment the column heading is "BankHolidayDate".

No, it can be any single-column table. If you have a SharePoint list with more columns, you can use something like ShowColumns(BankHolidayDates, BankHolidayDate) (*) to extract a single column table from there.
(*) If your Power Apps version is less than 3.24042, you'll need to use ShowColumns(BankHolidayDates, "BankHolidayDate") - see https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-fx-no-more-columns-names-in-text-strings/ for more details.
